# How to fix Micronaut maven build failure

Tags: java, maven, micronaut

I'm trying to mvn clean install, but it fails with the message: There are test failures. When I run all tests using IDE they pass and I need to skip tests.

Annotation processors it's enable as described here [Configuring IntelliJ IDEA](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#ideSetup)

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running dev.renansouza.document.DocumentFlowTest
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.011 sec
Running dev.renansouza.document.DocumentControllerTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 6, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.058 sec <<< FAILURE!
dev.renansouza.document.DocumentControllerTest.testInvoiceFailed()  Time elapsed: 0.039 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at dev.renansouza.document.DocumentControllerTest.testInvoiceFailed(DocumentControllerTest.java:35)

dev.renansouza.document.DocumentControllerTest.testInvoiceSuccess()  Time elapsed: 0.002 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at dev.renansouza.document.DocumentControllerTest.testInvoiceSuccess(DocumentControllerTest.java:45)

dev.renansouza.document.DocumentControllerTest.testSendZipFile()  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at dev.renansouza.document.DocumentControllerTest.testSendZipFile(DocumentControllerTest.java:57)

dev.renansouza.document.DocumentControllerTest.testSendYmlFile()  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at dev.renansouza.document.DocumentControllerTest.testSendYmlFile(DocumentControllerTest.java:80)

dev.renansouza.document.DocumentControllerTest.testInvoiceSuccessJWTToken()  Time elapsed: 0.002 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at dev.renansouza.document.DocumentControllerTest.testInvoiceSuccessJWTToken(DocumentControllerTest.java:102)

dev.renansouza.document.DocumentControllerTest.testJWTTokenRefresh()  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at dev.renansouza.document.DocumentControllerTest.testJWTTokenRefresh(DocumentControllerTest.java:115)

Running dev.renansouza.document.DocumentEnvironmentTest
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.019 sec

Results :

Failed tests:   dev.renansouza.document.DocumentControllerTest.testInvoiceFailed()
  dev.renansouza.document.DocumentControllerTest.testInvoiceSuccess()
  dev.renansouza.document.DocumentControllerTest.testSendZipFile()
  dev.renansouza.document.DocumentControllerTest.testSendYmlFile()
  dev.renansouza.document.DocumentControllerTest.testInvoiceSuccessJWTToken()
  dev.renansouza.document.DocumentControllerTest.testJWTTokenRefresh()

Tests run: 6, Failures: 6, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  22.813 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-09T11:04:27-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) on project invoice-unpack: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/renan/git/document-unpack/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

[image]

The code can be found here: https://github.com/renansouza-dev/document-unpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not configured the surefire plugin.  This requirement is described at https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/index.html#junit5.

You want something like https://github.com/jeffbrown/document-unpack/commit/724bac324130bd73a06e05f9129cae7e8e8eb1b4.

I have submitted a PR at https://github.com/renansouza-dev/document-unpack/pull/4.

Comment: Thanks again, Jeff!